# Alarm sound - doesn't always play

Tags: java, android

I am in the process of writing an alarm program. Most of it appears to work fine. I can set a time for the alarm to go off. When this time comes around my broadcast receiver initiates an activity which vibrates, makes a sound and displays a button to allow the user to stop the sound. When I run the program I can set the alarm to ring in a minute or two. I can then quit the alarm program and go and run something else. Sure enough when the alarm time comes, I get interrupted by the alarm activity, the phone vibrates, the alarm sounds and I see the button. I hear the sound even if the media volume is turned right down.

The problem is that if the phone is sleeping, then at the alarm time the phone will vibrate, but I hear no sound. When I wake the phone up I see the button on screen correctly.

I have looked at a large number of different code snippets for how to make the alarm sound. They all seem inordinately complicated and surprisingly different from each other. I don't fully understand any of them. What I have used is a conglomerate of several snippets shown below:

```
alarm_sound = new MediaPlayer();

Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
if(alert == null){
    // alert is null, using backup
    alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    if(alert == null){  // I can't see this ever being null (as always have a default notification) but just incase
        // alert backup is null, using 2nd backup
        alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);               
    }
}

 try {
        alarm_sound.setDataSource(this, alert);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) 
 {

                alarm_sound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                alarm_sound.setLooping(true);
                try {
                    alarm_sound.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                alarm_sound.start();
  }
```

Can anyone tell me how to correct my code so that it rings properly... or perhaps give me a web link to a site which explains it *simply*.

**EDIT:** I thought that perhaps the problem could be resolved by waking up the phone first. To do this I added the following code before any of the alarm of vibrate stuff:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
wakeLock.acquire();

PowerManager pm2 = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock2 = pm2.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
wakeLock2.acquire();
```

I also added the following to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

This code appeared to only half work - the phone did wake up in as much as the screen became lit up, but the lock was still on, i.e. I had to perform the slide-to-unlock operation myself. And just to add insult to injury, the alarm still didn't make a sound :-(

**EDIT:**: I just added `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);` 
for my main window. This bypassed the lock problem - but still no sound.